# Why is this i = (a += 2) giving SyntaxError in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute `exec('global expression_result; expression_result = %s' % "a += 2")` in python.

It is giving me `SyntaxError`. I have already declared the variables `a and expression_result`.

In ipython, I have also tried  `i = (a += 2)`  this is also giving the `SyntaxError`

How to evaluate these kinds of expressions and get the result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should not use `exec` or `eval`. There is almost never a need for either of these functions.

Second, an assignment (e.g., `a+=2`) is *not an expression* in Python (unlike C, C++, or Java). It does not have a value and cannot be printed or further assigned. You can split your code into two assignments, as advised by other commenters:

```
a += 2
i = a
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it with the `+=` sign.

But if you write it full it works.

```
i = a = a + 2
```

so drop `i = a += 2` which is basically the shortcut for `i = a = a + 2`

Answer (score 4):

As noted by the other answers, `a += 2` is not an expression in Python, so it cannot be written where an expression is expected (e.g. the right-hand-side of another assignment).

If you do want to write an assignment as an expression, this is possible since Python 3.8 using the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), but you can only use it for simple assignments, not compound assignments:

```py
expression_result = (a := a + 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your code and also, got a syntax error, any way you can use two lines?:

```
i = a
i += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
a+=2
i=a
```